# Is there a 'reserved field identifier' or similar, in ZPL?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I've been doing some work with ZPL recently for printing manufacturing barcode labels etc.

We have several fields on a custom label format that get replaced with real world data, by searching for a specific string of text in the raw ZPL, and then replacing it with the correct application data. E.g. `field1` just gets replaced by whatever we actually need to print there, before the TCP packet is constructed and put onto the network to perform the actual print.

This works just fine (so far), but I'm concerned what if some of our field data ever matches the format of a ZPL command for example, what happens.

Page 48 of the **huge** [ZPL specification document](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) shows what we are doing too, where `xxxxxxxxxxx` is the data to be replaced.

```
^XA
^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDxxxxxxxxxxx
^FS
^XZ
```

Is there no formal 'reserved field' format/identifier of sorts, or doing what we're doing the only option?

E.g. search and replace field1 in the ZPL below.

```
^XA
^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDfield1
^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Not only the data in `^FD` must be escaped, it must be escaped differently depending on whether it is output with an `^FO`, `^FB` or `^TB` (and even more rules if the data block describes a barcode). So your text replacer must be aware in which way to escape the data before replacing.

Comment: @Gserg thanks for the super quick response. I'm afraid I don't understand it though at all! We are using both plain text fields, and ECC200 barcodes - both of which 'work' because all our barcode contents is printable ASCII characters only (by our own internal standard). Please could you elaborate some? E.g. the manual says nothing about escaping contents of a ^FD field, other than not to use ~ or ^, but I read your comment as saying there is some special escape sequence/characters. Thanks again!

Comment: Look in the descriptions of `^FB` and `^TB` for more escape rules (pages 185 and 360). Also in the descriptions of individual barcodes.

Answer (score 1):

If what you have to replace in the ZPL code is the content of a field (text or barcode), you can try a different approach and use the ^FN command which is used as a placeholder for variable fields and it is usually used to [store and recall templates](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/advanced-solutions/printers-store-and-recall-a-template) from the printer memory.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for another solid option to look into!

Comment: @jwilo While `^FN` may or may not be convenient per se, it does not abstract away the need to escape the data differently depending on what printer command ultimately prints it out. You just have to do the escaping at the point of `^FN`ing rather than `^FD`ing. `^FN` actually makes it worse, because with `^FN` you have only one place where you substitute the data, and if that data is output with different commands on the same label, you cannot escape it in two ways at all. Consider the following label with `^FN` where the same data prints correctly in one case and not in another: ...

Comment: @jwilo http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EDFR%3A1.zpl%5EFS%0A%5EFO25%2C25%5EAD%2C36%2C20%5EFB500%2C2%5EFN1%5EFS%0A%5EFO25%2C150%5EAD%2C36%2C20%5EFN1%5EFS%0A%5EXZ%0A%0A%5EXA%0A%5EXFR%3A1.zpl%5EFS%0A%5EFN1%5EFDLine%201%5C%26Line%202%5EFS%0A%5EXZ

Comment: I believe the escaping is a non issue for jiwlo as the script seek and replace the text into the zpl code, so he just need a placeholder to replace with the actual data and it can be anything, like the xxxxxxx he used in the example. I think he's just looking for a solution embedded into the zpl programming language

Comment: @ZRep "*This works just fine (so far), but I'm concerned what if some of our field data ever matches the format of a ZPL command for example, what happens*"